# Login and scrape a remote website using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a login page [https://www.mywebsite.com/login](https://web.archive.org/web/20190712041152/http://www.mywebsite.com:80/login),
and a landing page to scrape [https://www.mywebsite.com/home](https://web.archive.org/web/20040713033852/http://www.mywebsite.com:80/home/).

I want to create a script, preferred written in Node.JS back end server for running in the background without user interaction, that will login through login page, and navigate to the landing page after login, redirect with cookies validated through login.

So basically, it is a script that follows redirection from login page, through landing page without losing the cookies just like a modern browser does.

I have ideas in mind what I'm looking for but I don't know what's the best thing or best approach to use in order to achieve my goals. Any help would be appreciated.

I prefer Node.js as recommendation but open for many other possibilities.

Comment: What's the purpose of this scrape? Bear in mind that our honest may just be that you should not do this, perhaps due to copyright ownership or privacy issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/), which is a headless browser that might support the functionality that you are looking for. Check out their [cookie documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/cookies.html) as well. I hope this is helpful!